# automation tests execution on mobile devices

Tags: node.js, typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In order to address the question, I have to shortly brief you:

- I'm writing and running e2e-automated-tests in order to test our company's web-site;
- the purpose is off-course, to make sure we have the site tested on both desktop and mobile phones;
- our tests are written in **typescript**, under a **node.js** environment, using **[Testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/)**;
- for desktop testing, Testcafe does an excellent job, of executing the tests on whatever local browsers I have installed on the testing environment;
- to execute the same e2e-automated-tests, on a mobile phone, we're using an integration of Testcafe with browserstack; so whatever tests I have, are executed on the real devices that browserstack platform provides;
- as we are not fully pleased with Browserstack, we're trying to find an alternative for browserstack;

Questions:

1. for mobile phone devices: **what are you guys using, to run/execute your e2e-automated-tests on mobile devices, having in mind the above configuration?**
2. what about taking Testcafe out of this discussion, and addressing the question again: **what are you guys using, to run/execute your e2e-automated-tests on mobile devices, having in mind the above configuration (but without Testcafe)?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure what exactly are you asking. To execute tests TestCafe is using proxy that injects test code to the page being tested. Therefore it does not care what browser it is in, as long as it can execute JavaScript. So this can be a mobile browser too.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be unclear, so, pls, maybe this helps: so I'm executing the e2e_tests on a virtual machine that has Chrome, Firefox and IE installed => this should cover check our web site, from a testing on desktop point of view; also, because it's a web site, I want to test how it reacts if you access it form a mobile phone, for example; now, for this, I can use the emulation from dev tools under Chrome, I could use some sites that are emulating this as well, or, browserstack, that uses real devices, but we have problems with it; what I would want, is an alternative to browserstack :)

Comment: I'm effectively interested what other automation QA's use, to test their teams apps/websites/etc ON mobile phone devices :)

Comment: As an alternative to the Browserstack, you can try Saucelabs devices provider. I believe that there is a [TestCafe connector](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs) for it. Or it is possible to create the homemade devices\emulators lab, but it is a hard way.

Comment: yes, best idea of the day :)), will do that
but still the questions are opened and I would appreciate each and every feedback

Comment: We at DevExpress used to have a farm of real mobile devices (with custom testcafe connector), and end up with system using ios and adroid emulators with different images (and a custom testcafe connector). But our case is quite rare - for some tests we needed very specific versions of OS or browser.

Comment: Well, I've read something about you having mobile phones testing for the paid version. It's much clearer now, 10X :). I would like to try out with real mobile devices testing first, and then get to the emulators. As emulators are quite close to real devices, there isn't yet a perfect emulator. There are some differences so that means of course some issue might occur due to that. BTW, could you maybe tell  which is the most used mobile phone emulator, that can be integrated with Testcafe?

Comment: @Eugen i'll check with a team tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect your iOS or Android device to TestCafe as a remote browser by using a QR code: [Remote Browsers](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#remote-browsers).

There are also third-party browser plugins for testing on mobile devices: [testcafe-browser-provider-idevice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-provider-idevice) and [testcafe-browser-provider-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-provider-android).

As far as I know, the most popular approach to mobile testing used by SauceLabs and BrowserStack is installing [Appium](http://appium.io/) on your devices. You can use [testcafe-browser-provider-selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-provider-selenium) to run TestCafe tests on devices with Appium.

I see that you're against using mobile simulators, but if you change your mind, you can use the [Chrome emulation mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/using-chrome-device-emulation.html) and [testcafe-browser-provider-fbsimctl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-provider-fbsimctl) with TestCafe.

Comment: a lot of options, and I'm pretty sure I will find one that suits us; 10Q Andrey

Comment: Thank you for using TestCafe ;)